# How to get latest 5 results from MySQL database using Spring,Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I need some help to fix my issue. I'm having a `REST webservices` project with `Spring` and `Hibernate`. By executing the `POST` call in `POSTMAN`,I've inserted some details into `MySQL` database. So, now i need to get latest 4(which means last 4) from the database table using `GET`

`---id--------|----testname---|----testmethod----|---groupname---|-result----`

So, these above mentioned are the columns of my database table. so i need to get last 4 results based on `column groupname`. So, i need to search by `groupname`and `id`. The values of groupname will be like `[Test]`. So, can anyone tell is there any way to get those details through `GET` call.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: What does your query look like so far?

Comment: Are you using JPA?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp column?

Comment: @stdunbar i don't have any timestamp colum. Is it necessary?

Comment: @Strawberry. I don't have any solution. I just need some suggestions to how to do that.

Comment: Reading the Spring/hibernate documentation would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: @HatemJaber. no,I'm not using JPA. I just used Spring and Hibernate to insert, get, put intlo MySQL database

Comment: @KevinHooke. sorry i don't have any query.

Comment: @thermite. I'll look into them. may be that would help.

Comment: Are you planning on using Hibernate's Criteria API? If not, then you'll need an HQL query to select what it is that you're looking for. Probably digging into the docs to work out how to execute a query would help at this point, and then if you need further help you can post what you have so far with your query, and then others can help you from there.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve some specific number of rows from database using hibernate then you can do something like this

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
cr.setFirstResult(1);
cr.setMaxResults(4);
List results = cr.list();
```

The above code will retrieve first 4 rows from your DB.

If you want to retrieve last 4 rows then you have to somehow count the number of rows then use code like this

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
cr.setFirstResult(count-4);
cr.setMaxResults(count);
List results = cr.list();
```

it will give you last 4 rows from your DB.

if you want to use HQL then you can do something like this

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM table");
q.setFirstResult(start);
q.setMaxResults(maxRows);
```

Comment: No, this will get 4 random rows from the database.  The OP's database will never be able to guarantee which data it's getting because there is no ability to order by time.